# Is it possible to do bit reversal for a 16 bit number only using shift left, xor, and bitwise operations on python

Tags: python, binary

I was wondering if it is possible to do bit reversal for a 16bit binary number such as 1000000000000011 to 1100000000000001 by only using the shift left >>, Xor ^, And & functions on python? Adding and subtracting binary can also be used for this problem

Comment: In order to do a bit reversal you need to shift bits in both directions.

Comment: Since you said `>>` perhaps you meant right shift instead of left shift?  In that case it might be possible, since adding a number to itself is the equivalent of a left shift by 1.

Comment: Hey mark, thank you for your response! My bad i meant << for the left shift, the problem specifically states that you cant use right shift and only allowed to use the operators i stated above

Comment: I forgot to add that, the python code is converted into assembly language meaning that if we shift the 16bit number to the left 16 times it will return to its original value

Comment: Obviously you're not solving the problem in Python then, because that's not how Python works.  Try `bin(1 << 16)` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

The description you give in the comments for "left shift" is not what Python does for `<<` - you're describing what would be called a "left rotate".  Since Python doesn't provide that, let's code it up quick:

```
def circular_shift_16(x, n):
    assert(0 <= x <= 0xffff)
    return (( x << n) & 0xffff) | (x >> (16-n))
```

With that as a building block, you can do the bit reversal.

```
def bit_reversal_16(x):
    # reverse single bit pairs
    x = (circular_shift_16(x, 15) & 0x5555) ^ (circular_shift_16(x, 1) & 0xaaaa)
    # reverse groups of 2
    x = (circular_shift_16(x, 14) & 0x3333) ^ (circular_shift_16(x, 2) & 0xcccc)
    # reverse groups of 4
    x = (circular_shift_16(x, 12) & 0x0f0f) ^ (circular_shift_16(x, 4) & 0xf0f0)
    # reverse groups of 8
    x = circular_shift_16(x, 8)
    return x
```